# (Python)how to group rows by first column, not sorting by order?

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have a quite oddly structured csv file. The column fields are composed of numbers, and the lines are partly, but not perfectly grouped by the first column field.
For example, if the column data is {number1, number2, number3}, the file would look like:

**321**, 12, 4932
**321**, 32, 4643
**321**, 95, 3921
...
143, 98, 2432
143, 28, 3910
...
*832*, 43, 2910
*832*, 54, 2190
...
572, 91, 8492
572, 92, 9302
572, 15, 3902
...
**321**, 93, 7281
**321**, 48, 6218
...
*832*, 78, 0148
*832*, 91, 7281

The problem is that I need the file to be perfectly grouped by the first column, so that the above example should be:

321, 12, 4932
321, 32, 4643
321, 95, 3921
321, 93, 7281
321, 48, 6218
...
143, 98, 2432
143, 28, 3910
...
832, 43, 2910
832, 54, 2190
832, 78, 0148
832, 91, 7281
...
572, 91, 8492
572, 92, 9302
572, 15, 3902
...

.. and also at the same time, as it is shown above, the first column should not be sorted in order. I need the first column order to be the same(which could sound weird, but since it is partly grouped it has certain order in a large scale).

What could be the fastest algorithm to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrange the rows into lists which are stored in a dict keyed by the first column. Use an OrderedDict if you wish to preserve the order in which you read them from the original spreadsheet. Something like this (untested code)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
...
d = OrderedDict()

# open the csv file as reader

for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    d.setdefault(key,[]).append(row)
```

and to use the result

```
for key,rowlist in d.items()
    for row in rowlist:
       # do whatever with row
```

Comment: I used OrderedDict and it did the job good enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try hardcoding it as such but for CSV files in Python I would recommend using Pandas. Pandas is an `import` for Python specifically created for CSV files. You can sort, group, create data sets, etc, fairly simply. You can also read the CSV file and create custom columns and rows. such as :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [321,143,832]})
```

I'll leave some documentation links where you can find which function best suits your needs to implement in Python.
 [Basic Tutorial .](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/01%20-%20Lesson.ipynb) 
[Scroll to Grouping](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)  [Tutorial with Examples](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-tutorial-dataframe-python#gs.TR=XOy0)

Easiest and quickest way would be to use Pandas for your CSV

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list and a dictionary while parsing the file, using the dictionary to group the lines by the first row and the list to preserve the first rows' order:

```
grouped_rows = {}
rows = []
with open("your_file") as ins:
    for line line in ins:
        first = line.split(",")[0]
        if first in rows:
            grouped_rows[first].append(line)
            continue
        rows.append(first)
        grouped rows[first] = [line]
```

Then you can print them by simply parsing the list and retrieving the data from the dictionary:

```
for row in rows:
    print "\n".join(grouped_rows[row])
```